# How can you programmatically format content to paste into Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, clipboard, copy-paste

Say you want to copy a CSV like this:

```
foo,1,"asdf"
bar,2,"fdsa"
baz,3,"helloworld"
```

You copy it with CMD+C/CTRL+C, then go to Google Spreadsheets and press CMD+V/CTRL+V, and you end up with one cell containing all the content. Not what I was hoping for...

How can you format it using JavaScript and the clipboard so it pastes each row/cell into the proper place in the spreadsheet? I have this to do the copying to clipboard in JavaScript:

```
const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
textarea.style.opacity = 0
textarea.style.width = 0
textarea.style.height = 0
textarea.style.position = 'absolute'
textarea.style.bottom = '-100%'
textarea.style.left = '-100%'
textarea.style.margin = 0
document.body.appendChild(textarea)

const copy = function(text){
  textarea.value = text
  textarea.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  copy(
`foo,1,"asdf"
bar,2,"fdsa"
baz,3,"helloworld"`
  )
}
```

How to format it so the Spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheets formats it as rows and columns properly?

Comment: Is this proper content for SO? It involves JavaScript but I don't know that it fits here better than another place like SuperUser

Comment: I feel like SO people would know best, superuser aren't very into frontend JS I don't think.

Comment: True, but what I'm asking is whether you need JS in the first place. Have you tried importing the CSV into Google Sheets and transferring the cells from there?

Comment: Something to remember is that the best code is no code

Comment: Adding the tab worked, thanks!

Comment: @TheFool I wouldn't, this isn't a Stack Overflow question. This is general computing

Comment: its totally fine on SO, imo.

Comment: The solution was just "use TSV instead of CSV". That's not a programming question, there's a place for questions like this. It should be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: Then cast your vote, my friend.

Comment: It's not a bad question, it just doesn't belong here lol. I've already flagged it to get it migrated

Comment: So then, we can stop discussing. Let's just wait and see what happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace comma with tabs and it should work. This is standard behavior in sheets and also excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = [
[
// Cell values ...
],
// Additional rows ...
];
var body = {
values: values
};
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
range: range,
valueInputOption: valueInputOption,
resource: body
}).then((response) => {
var result = response.result;
console.log(`${result.updatedCells} cells updated.`);
});
```

This is a method provided in by google sheets api and modify upto your needs
here is link
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#javascript_1